# Vaadin 22 opened ComboBox does not position correctly

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

I'm upgrading a Vaadin application from 14 to 22.

The app features some dialogs with combo boxes that have dozens of items.

In version 14, when opening a combo box near the bottom of the dialog (which is also near the bottom of the screen unless the browser window is very large), the list of items automatically gets positioned **above** the input field, so that a decent amount of items are visible.

After the upgrade to version 22, this doesn't work anymore: the list of items appears **below** the input field, even if there is only space for one or two items, which makes it hard to use for the user.

I did notice that when the combo box is opened below the input field, resizing the browser window causes the list of items to immediately flip to above the input field, showing more items.  So it seems to be a bug where the position is not properly calculated initially.

Is there any way to work around this by forcing a recalculation of the position programmatically?

Comment: Just wanted to note that there is an issue that tracks this: https://github.com/vaadin/flow-components/issues/2820. The issue mentions that even just scrolling fixes it, so maybe manually dispatching a scroll event could be a workaround.

Comment: @SaschaIßbrücker thanks for the issue link!